# Controlling user access to groups of resources with Azure AD Groups or Roles?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We currently have a simple AspNet Core website that is logged into by a "Manager". It gives them access to data about company branches they manage and the customers that use those branches.

The managers have an account in our Azure AD organisation. Currently we some appRoles defined in the website's [App Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps). We have an appRole for each branch called "BRANCHNAME_Managers" this feels more like a Group. From memory I think we had problems accessing the groups a user was in from within the website so used the appRoles as they appear in the ClaimsPrincipal.Claims.

We want to create an api that is called from that website. That api needs to know what branches a manager manages. That api would have a seperate app registration in Azure AD and it seems that appRoles configured in the Web Site App registration would not be passed through to the web api. Therefore I think we need to move away from appRoles defined in the WebSite App Registration. Is this correct?

Bearing in mind what we are are trying to control access to, the branches a manager manages and the customers that are related to those branches should we be using User Groups membership or something we roll ourselves with simple database relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App roles defined in the website app registration (client app) cannot be recognized by the API. The app roles only exist in the id token in this case. But we need to verify the access token to access the API.

As I answered in your previous post, you can define the same app roles in the API app registration (service app) and assign those roles to the same managers.

Then you can verify the app roles included in the access token for your API.